# Renaming files with Chinese characters in Python

Tags: python, windows, unicode, filesystems

I'm trying to rename some files that have Chinese characters. However, the following won't work:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\mas\Desktop\"):
    if filename.startswith("你好"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
```

it gives the error " The system cannot find the file specified: '你好 Hello.txt"

Do I need to change some settings or something here?

Comment: `os.rename()` is looking for the file in the current directory, which probably isn't the same as the directory you passed to `os.listdir()`.  Use `os.path.join()` to put the two pieces together to make a full pathname.

Comment: Also, if this is Python 2, then you need to use a `unicode` string to reliably handle Unicode file paths. Python 2 `str` is a byte string, and prior to 3.6, bytes paths use the Windows [A]NSI API (e.g. `CreateFileA` instead of wide-character `CreateFileW`). In this case Windows best-fit decodes the bytes path using the system locale's ANSI codepage. (In Python 3.6, the default file-system encoding was changed to UTF-8, and internally bytes paths are decoded as UTF-16LE to use the Windows wide-character API.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems the file is not found

I came across similar problem, and I solved it by changing current working directory first

In your case

```py
# Change working directory first
os.chdir("C:\Users\mas\Desktop")

# then do the loop
for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\mas\Desktop\"):
    ...
```